# request is not coming to controller while using Spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have Spring MVC project to develop sample REST api. It was running when I deploy app in tomcat. Now, I wanted to update the project with Spring boot. I have created the main spring boot application class which is as below at package: com.abc.demo.config

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration  // Sprint Boot Auto Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc.demo")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(applicationClass);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }
    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

}
```

My controller is at com.abc.demo.Controller which is like below:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mytask/{task}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
     public int myTask(@PathVariable String task) {
        return myService.service(task);
    }

}
```

When I deploy the application in local tomcat without adding spring boot, it was deploying and I am able to see the response from the service. (I had web.xml and dispatcher servlet as well while app was running). But, when I added spring boot and run the app from command line, app is running (I have run some threads when app starts, when I can see running). But when I do curl, request is not coming to controller at all and seeing the URI not found log in console as :No mapping found for HTTP request with URI as [/[myservice-name]/myTask
Did I miss something here? Appreciate if someone points out the things I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with the framework not around it. Move your `Application` to `com.abc.demo` (or the actual root package of your project). then remove most of it. All your annotation can be replaced by a simple `@SpringBootApplication`. Don't create a `DispatcherServlet` Spring Boot already does that for you as well as configuration Spring MVC.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(applicationClass);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }    
}
```

You can also polish your controller a little as you have `@RestController` you don't need the `@ResponseBody`.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mytask/{task}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")        
     public int myTask(@PathVariable String task) {
        return myService.service(task);
    }
}
```

Finally I would say your url you are using is wrong. By default, when running from the command line, the application is available as the root application i.e. on `/` and not on `/myservice/mytask/{task}`.

So try `curl http://localhost:8080/mytask/123` instead of including the application name.

If you do want `/myservice` to be part of the URL you can specify a `server.context-path` in the `application.properties` for your application.

```
server.context-path=/myservice
```

Then it will be prepended to the URL.

Comment: Great Explanation Deinum. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass your [myservice-name].Use url like this

> http://localhost:8080/mytask/somevalue

Comment: yes. I did that after posting question here which worked.

Comment: @user8838 ok great

Answer (score 0):

Its a suggestion for people who are getting this problem:
Spring boot has already very simple process to create your set-up. Still if you are getting an error where your request is not reaching server

Most probably you would have done a common mistake of declaring your package out of the application context.
**First Step:**
your package should be inside your root package example: 
your controller should be inside com.example.demo if it is your root package.

**Second Step:**
create a simple request which just reach your RequestController like:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    public String testServer() {
        return "Server OK ";
    }
```

So that you can be assured that your request is reaching to this point.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to work with spring-boot in scala I leave it here to save your day. I had a similar situation where controller bean was created but no requests routed to it.

First I used mapping annotations copied from Java examples, like

```
@GetMapping("/path")
```

After some suffering I changed it to

```
@GetMapping(path = Array("/path"))
```

and finally it started working.